# Can I sell an Android app by taking someone's written work that is in a public domain, and then adding some of my work to it?

Tags: public-domain

publishers are selling their books by taking someone’s written work which is in public domain by adding some commentary, picture and translating it, so can I do the same by taking that work, adding a picture, some my own thoughts on it (commentary), making an android app and selling it

Answer (score 1):

If you take a public domain work (or a copyrighted work with permission) and repackage it (with or without extra material) you can sell it.

Shakespeare's plays and Bach's sheet music have been reckoned and replaced thousands if not hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: you made your answer a bit confusing by talking about two different things at a time. Basically you saying, it's yes that I can use that written work, which is in public domain and add my thoughts to it and sell it as an android application?